# Windows Azure: Web Page, Mobile Service and SQL

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

i am trying to develop a service using Windows Azure. The service consists in two parts:

- An Android app that inserts some contents into a SQL database (using Azure Mobile Services)
- A Web Site to show the SQL content.

The Andoird part is already done, the data is added into the SQL. The problem comes when I try to create the Web Site.

I followed some online tutorials [like this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/), or [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/).
It works just fine with a "normal" database Table, but when I try to use one of the Tables used by the Mobile Service, I just cannot get it working..

**I have tried:** (I thought it has something to be with the Schema Name)

- Setting a new user for the database with default_schema the one of the Mobile Service Database Tables
- Changing the default schema of DbContext (Using the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e276fb02-ef9b-44eb-b481-699c1c25602d/change-schemaname-for-ef-41-dbcontext?forum=adodotnetentityframework))

Right now, when I try to see the site that should show the Table contents, I get an HTTP 505 error...

Can anyone help me? Has anyone an idea? It will be much appreciated...

Thanks!

PS: I don't know if this is important, but I created the Tables using the "Manage" Azure website, under my Mobile Service, and after I got it working, then tried to implement the Web Site

Comment: I don't know if anyone has a similar problem. But In case it helps anyone: The problem solved by itself. I don't really know how or why, but I started again from scratch writing Webpage and it worked eventually...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already resolved it, but my guess is that you've got entity framework issues. Be sure you follow all the best practices like using Code First migration. If you're having issues with the SQL stuff, it's generally a problem of it not playing well together.